# Problema con el Mainactivity

Tags: android-studio

esperando que todos se encuentren muy bien de salud, les comento que estoy realizando mi primera aplicación, estuve realizando pruebas con los formularios, aplicando el crud completo y aprendiendo a utilizar los json (arreglo) y el spinner para llamar los datos, y ahora que quiero juntar lo que he hecho hasta la fecha en la aplicación completa, se realizó una actualización que me pidió android studio la cual se aplicó este viernes y del cual me arroja el problema en todo lo que he hecho, en el logcat se ve que me marca el error en el maincativity, por lo cual les presento el código utilizado en el activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/hoja"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="333dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoboton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="Maestro"
    android:text="@string/button"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="44dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="44dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="266dp"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoboton"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:onClick="Consorcio"
    android:text="@string/button1"
    android:textColor="@android:color/background_dark"
    android:textSize="18sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtpresentacion"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="540dp"
    android:autofillHints="txtpresentacion"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
    android:ems="10"
    android:enabled="false"
    android:fadeScrollbars="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/presentacion"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/teal_700"
    android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/txtpresentacion1"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="466dp"
    android:autofillHints="txtpresentacion1"
    android:background="@drawable/fondoet"
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:hint="@string/presentacion1"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:paddingRight="5dp"
    android:textColor="@color/purple_700"
    android:textColorHint="@color/purple_500"
    android:textSize="30sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

este es el código del mainactivity.java:

```
package com.example.oficina;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.util.Objects;
@SuppressWarnings("ALL")

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Objects.requireNonNull(getSupportActionBar()).setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
}

public void Maestro (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Mdimenu1.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}

public void Consorcio (View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,Mdimenu2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
}
```

este el código del AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.oficina">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Oficina"
    <activity
        android:name=".Mdimenu2"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Frmvaloruf"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Frmrepuestos"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmmarca" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmtaller" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmproveedores" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmcompania" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmcorredores" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmcasos1" />
    <activity android:name=".Mdimenu1" />
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

y este el listado en donde me aparece el error en el logcat:

```
2022-10-17 16:13:15.314 8496-8496/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.oficina, PID: 8496
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oficina/com.example.oficina.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:852)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:815)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:703)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
    **at com.example.oficina.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)**
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7136)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

ojala que me puedan ayudar en esta disyuntiva, ya que antes del viernes funcionaba todo bien y no poseo ningún error, este que me marca el error en el oncreate de Manincativity, y como pueden ver soy nuevo en estas lides de Android Studio, pero me gusta aprender por lo cual y desde ya muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El error se indica aquí:

> IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or
> descendant) with this activity.

El problema es el tema usado, en tu `AndroidManifest.xml` define para `MainActivity` el tema:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light"
```

---

Si estás usando un tema para toda tu aplicación, por ejemplo:

```
<application
android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
```

debes verificar en `styles.xml` que el tema definido tiene como padre el tema

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
```

Comment: muchas gracias por tu ayuda lo hice como me lo mencionaste, además de los otros cambios que realice

Answer (score 0):

amigos del foro les comento que realice el sigueinte cambio para mi problema, por si acaso les pasa lo mismo a otros novatos como yo.

- Lo primero que realice fue ir a dependencias del build gradle de la aplicación y las actualice, posteriormente cambie en el mismo archivo DefaultConfig del minsdk del 16 al 21, por lo cual realice el sync.
- Segundo me dirigí al android manifest y cambie un poco el código en la sección de aplicación, del cual quedo de la siguiente manera.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.Oficina">
    <activity
        android:name=".Mdimenu2"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Frmvaloruf"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Frmrepuestos"
        android:exported="true" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmmarca" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmtaller" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmproveedores" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmcompania" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmcorredores" />
    <activity android:name=".Frmcasos1" />
    <activity android:name=".Mdimenu1" />
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

posteriormente lo hice correr en el emulador y funciona muy bien, además de correrlo en una tablet antigua y del celular que poseo y funciona muy bien, ojala que les sirva a alguien más este problema.

Comment: Esto no es un foro. Es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. La relación es 1 pregunta - N respuestas. Es decir, cada pregunta solo debe tener respuestas que, valga la redundancia, respondan directamente a la pregunta con hechos, no opiniones.

Comment: @Mateo mis disculpas de antemano no se volverá a repetir, pensaba que era buena idea para gente nueva como yo que les gusta aprender nuevas tendencias y tecnologías, además de los desafíos que implica.

Comment: Si alguna respuesta que te hayan dado solucionó tu problema o te guió a la solución, acéptala. Si pudiste solucionarlo y ninguna de las respuestas te fue útil, considera hacer una donde expliques los pasos que seguiste.